# recursive haskell function hangs forever in interactive session

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a recursive function that plots some picture in ASCII art. It is quite simple being

```
type Picture = [[Char]]
white :: Picture
white = ["......",
         "......",
         "......",
         "......",
         "......",
         "......"]

black = ["######",
         "######",
         "######",
         "######",
         "######",
         "######"]

printPicture :: Picture -> IO ()
printPicture = putStr . concat . map (++"\n")
```

With these blocks I want to construct a game board. I have define some functions to do so, which are:

```
blackinWhite :: Integer -> Integer -> Picture
blackinWhite n m | n==1 && m==1 = black
                 | n==1 = white
                 | n==m = black `beside` blackinWhite (n-1) m
                 | otherwise = white `beside` blackinWhite (n-1) m

blackinWhite' :: Integer -> Integer -> Picture
blackinWhite' n m | n==1 && m==1 = black
                  | n==1 = white
                  | n==m = black `above` blackinWhite' (n-1) m
                  | otherwise = white `above` blackinWhite' (n-1) m

diagonalrug :: Integer -> Integer -> Picture
diagonalrug n m | m==1 = blackinWhite n m
                | otherwise = blackinWhite n m `above` diagonalrug n (m-1)

antidiagrug :: Integer -> Integer -> Picture
antidiagrug n m | m==1 = blackinWhite' n m
                | otherwise = antidiagrug n (m-1) `beside` blackinWhite' n m

crossedrug :: Integer -> Integer -> Picture
crossedrug n m | dimn /= 0 || dimm /= 0= error("Come back later")
               | otherwise = diagonalrug dimn dimm --((diagonalrug dimn dimm) `beside` (antidiagrug dimn dimm)) `above` ((antidiagrug dimn dimm) `beside` (diagonalrug dimn dimm))                                                           
               where
                 dimn = mod n 2
                 dimm = mod m 2
```

If I do in the interactive session:

```
*Main> diagonalrug 2 2
```

The program hangs and my computer is freezed. If I execute directly the statement that comes after `otherwise`, the result is given without any problems. Why if I call the function crossedrug ghci crashes?

(I am not providing the functions `above` and `beside`, since they simply concatenate two pictures that should be clear from the context.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow execution.

You're calling it with `2 2`, it goes to the otherwise and calls `diagonalrug 0 0` which in turn goes to the otherwise clause which never terminates since it calls `diagonalrug 0 -1` so `m` is never 1 (it keeps being negative).

`diagonalrug` is missing a stopping condition for that case.

Comment: Is the very first call `diagonalrug 2 2` or `crossedrug 2 2` in your answer? The OP posted the first, but maybe you are referring to the second?

Comment: I am tired and that's when one starts to do thrash XD. The thing is that I tried `diagonalrug 2 2` and this works ok, now I never noticed that I was using `crossedrug 2 2` and then uses `diagonalrug 0 0`, which then causes the problem as Benjamin pointed out.